# Can't add object to Array in jQuery's getJSON data function (scope issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have a person object and wants to store it into a global ArrayCollection I have made.
Works great in normal scope:

```
var s = new ArrayCollection();
s.add(new person("Knud", "Mikkelsen", 35));
```

The problem is when I want to add people inside my jQuery function "mainFunction".

I can't seem to get it right. I know it's something to do with scope and I have to wrap something in functions like in my ArrayCollection.
Please help me - thanks a lot.

```
function ArrayCollection() {
 var myArray = new Array;
 return {
  empty: function () {
   myArray.splice(0, myArray.length);
  },
  add: function (myElement) {
   myArray.push(myElement);
  },
  getAll: function () {
   return myArray;
  }
 }
}

function person(firstName, lastName, age) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.lastName = lastName;
 this.age = parseInt(parseFloat(age));
}

function mainFunction() {
 //....
 var s = new ArrayCollection();
 s.add(new person("Knud", "Mikkelsen", 35));

 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

   var myPerson = new person(data[x].FirstName.toString(), data[x].LastName.toString(), data[x].Age.toString());
   s.add(myPerson);
  }
 });

 alert(drawArray(s.getAll()));
}

function drawArray(myArray) {
 var v = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  v += myArray[i].firstName + " " + myArray[i].lastName + " (" + myArray[i].age + ")\n";
 }
 return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing a scope issue there. Your success function for `getJSON` is defined within `mainFunction` and so has access to `s`. `mainFunction` is defined as a peer of `person` and so has access to it.

I **am** seeing a synchronous/asynchronous issue. Here's the order of execution of `mainFunction`:

1. Create a new `ArrayCollection`.
2. Add a person to it named Knud Mikkelsen
3. Initiate a request for data via `$.getJSON`.
4. Alert showing the one person in the `ArrayCollection` (Knud Mikkelsen)
5. Return
6. At some point in the future, the `getJSON` call completes and adds the person objects to the `ArrayCollection`

This is because by default, `getJSON` is *asynchronous* — it completes at some point in the future, not synchronously with the code where it was initiated. This is a good thing because synchronous Ajax calls lock up the browser UI completely and make for a poor user experience.

Your options for actually seeing that person returned by the Ajax call are to move the alert to within the `getJSON` success handler, and/or to pass a callback into `mainFunction` that gets triggered by the `getJSON` completion function, and/or pass the `ArrayCollection` to add to into `mainFunction` and just check it for new person objects later as part of your program flow.

Here are a couple of options for you:

Just move the `alert` inside the `getJSON` completion function:

```
function mainFunction() {
    //....
    var s = new ArrayCollection();
    s.add(new person("Knud", "Mikkelsen", 35));

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            var myPerson = new person(data[x].FirstName.toString(), data[x].LastName.toString(), data[x].Age.toString());
            s.add(myPerson);
        }
        alert(drawArray(s.getAll())); // <== moved this into the completion function
    });
}
```

Or use a callback:

```
function mainFunction(callback) {
    //....
    var s = new ArrayCollection();
    s.add(new person("Knud", "Mikkelsen", 35));

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            var myPerson = new person(data[x].FirstName.toString(), data[x].LastName.toString(), data[x].Age.toString());
            s.add(myPerson);
        }
        callback(s);                // <== Trigger callback, passing in the collection
    });
}

function mainFunctionCallback(s) {
    alert(drawArray(s.getAll()));   // <== Moved out of `mainFunction` entirely
}

// Usage:
mainFunction(mainFunctionCallback);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Lol sometimes it's the simplest things you forget to think about.